# Count how many categories each column of categorical variable in python pandas automatically

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset that consist of hundreds of categorical variable, after selecting categorical variable category only using `features_categorical = features_old.select_dtypes(exclude=["number"])`

For feature engineering purpose I need to split category that has more than 5 category using this method

```
In : features_categorical['Variable 1'].unique()
Out : array(['Category_1', 'Category_2'], dtype=object)
```

But, its too manual, because I need to do this in every variable, since I need to do for hundreds variable

How to do directly in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
df = features_old.select_dtypes(include='category')
result = df.apply(pd.Series.unique)
```

If you wanna select everything except number then use:

```
df = features_old.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
result = df.apply(pd.Series.unique)
```

If you want the count then use `nunique`:

```
df = features_old.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
result = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
result = result[result > 5]
```

The 1st line will select the subset of the dataframe (excluding number dtypes). The second line will evaluate the category count. Then the 3rd one will filter those values where the count is greater than 5.

Comment: It's not working on my case, because when I input `df['Column_C'].dtypes` the output is `dtype('O')`

Comment: Then try: df = features_old.select_dtypes(exclude=["number"])

Comment: That isn't my question, my question is how to count how many category in each column automatically

Comment: Reread my question. Its too manual, because I need to do this in every variable, since I need to do for hundreds variable. How to do directly in dataframe?

Comment: @NabihBawazir The 1st line will select the subset of the dataframe (excluding number dtypes). The second line will evaluate the category count. Then the 3rd one will filter those values where the count is greater than 5. What's manual work in this? can you explain?. I'm not hardcoding any variable name anywhere.